# How to add product grid in custom module's tab?

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, product-grid

I want to add a product grid in my module's tab.

How can I achieve this?

Please help me.

I tried [this](http://webkul.com/blog/magento2-display-grid-tab-magento-admin/). But I am getting a blank page.

Comment: Take a look at this sample module: https://github.com/tzyganu/Magento2SampleModule. it may not be up to date with the latest magento version, but it will give you a place to start

Comment: Is there any other extension in latest magento ?

Comment: I don't have one. I didn't get around to make it compatible.

Comment: @Marius  I have update my ans.Please check.This may help me

Comment: Please follow my answer and save selected products into database.https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/236854/magento-2-2-5-how-to-create-grid-in-tabs/315875#315875

Answer (score 4):

> Namespace: Vendor
>
> ModuleName: Productattach

**Example: https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-productAttachment**

**1) Create controller**

> app/code/Vendor/Productattach/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/ProductsGrid.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Productattach\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\TestFramework\ErrorLog\Logger;

class ProductsGrid extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory
     */
    protected $_resultLayoutFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
     * @param Action\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_resultLayoutFactory = $resultLayoutFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultLayout = $this->_resultLayoutFactory->create();
        $resultLayout->getLayout()->getBlock('productattach.edit.tab.products')
                     ->setInBanner($this->getRequest()->getPost('index_products', null));

        return $resultLayout;
    }

}
```

**2) Create layout**

> app/code/Vendor/Productattach/view/adminhtml/layout

/productattach_index_productsgrid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <container name="root" label="Root">
        <block class="Vendor\Productattach\Block\Adminhtml\Productattach\Edit\Tab\Products" name="productattach.edit.tab.products"/>
    </container>
</layout>
```

**3) Create block which we defined in layout file**

> app/code/Vendor/Productattach/Block/Adminhtml/Productattach/Edit/Tab/Products.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Productattach\Block\Adminhtml\Productattach\Edit\Tab;

use Vendor\Productattach\Model\ProductattachFactory;

class Products extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * Contact factory
     *
     * @var ContactFactory
     */
    protected $contactFactory;

    /**
     * @var  \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    protected $_objectManager = null;

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param ContactFactory $attachmentFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        ProductattachFactory $contactFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->contactFactory = $contactFactory;
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * _construct
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('productsGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('productattach_id')) {
            $this->setDefaultFilter(array('in_product' => 1));
        }
    }

    /**
     * add Column Filter To Collection
     */
    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        if ($column->getId() == 'in_product') {
            $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();

            if (empty($productIds)) {
                $productIds = 0;
            }
            if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));
            } else {
                if ($productIds) {
                    $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => $productIds));
                }
            }
        } else {
            parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * prepare collection
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('sku');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        /* @var $model \Webspeaks\ProductsGrid\Model\Slide */
        $model = $this->_objectManager->get('\Vendor\Productattach\Model\Productattach');

        $this->addColumn(
            'in_product',
            [
                'header_css_class' => 'a-center',
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => 'in_product',
                'align' => 'center',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'values' => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('Product ID'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'names',
            [
                'header' => __('Name'),
                'index' => 'name',
                'class' => 'xxx',
                'width' => '50px',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'sku',
            [
                'header' => __('Sku'),
                'index' => 'sku',
                'class' => 'xxx',
                'width' => '50px',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'price',
            [
                'header' => __('Price'),
                'type' => 'currency',
                'index' => 'price',
                'width' => '50px',
            ]
        );

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/productsgrid', ['_current' => true]);
    }

    /**
     * @param  object $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return '';
    }

    protected function _getSelectedProducts()
    {
        $contact = $this->getContact();
        return $contact->getProducts($contact);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve selected products
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSelectedProducts()
    {
        $contact = $this->getContact();
        $selected = $contact->getProducts($contact);

        if (!is_array($selected)) {
            $selected = [];
        }
        return $selected;
    }

    protected function getContact()
    {
        $contactId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('productattach_id');
        $contact   = $this->contactFactory->create();
        if ($contactId) {
            $contact->load($contactId);
        }
        return $contact;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I move above product grid from **Select Products** tab to **Attachment Information** tab ?

Comment: @Prince, what is setInBanner in Controller?

Comment: @Prince how can i get selected product in post?

Comment: Hi @prince how can I add new product tab above filter section in product grid??

Comment: Please follow this and save selected product in databse https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/236854/magento-2-2-5-how-to-create-grid-in-tabs/315875#315875

Comment: @Prince I am getting error like "Call to a member function setInBanner() on bool ". I am showing custom grid in tab with this structure, but the grid is not loaded and giving me error.

Answer (score 0):

As an example you can take a look on [Sales Order View layout](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml). It includes invoice, shipment and creditmemo grids under separate tabs on order view page.

Basically it's adding a container tab:

```
    <block class="..." name="sales_order_tabs">
        ...
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Invoices" name="sales_order_invoice.grid.container"/>
        <action method="addTab">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_invoices</argument>
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_order_invoice.grid.container</argument>
        </action>
        ...
    </block>
```

And including ui component:

```
<referenceBlock name="sales_order_invoice.grid.container">
    <uiComponent name="sales_order_view_invoice_grid"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

To include product grid you should do the same in your module using **product_listing** ui component (see [catalog_product_index](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_index.xml) layout).