# Magento 2.2.5: How to create Grid in Tabs?

Tags: grid, magento-2.2.5, tabs

I'm looking for the way to do Grid in Tabs in Magento 2.2.5, I have searched a lot, but almost what I found is from 2016 and so on.

Doesn't match with Magento 2.2.5 anymore.

Ok so what I need to do is look like this.

[image]

I'm after this but not working.
http://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/how-to-add-custom-grid-into-a-custom-tab-in-product-edit-page-in-magento-2-admin/

**EDIT 1:**

Here is my ui-component banner_form.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">banner_form.banner_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General Information</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>

    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="save_and_continue" class="Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton"/>
            <button name="save" class="Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\SaveButton"/>
            <button name="reset" class="Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\ResetButton"/>
            <button name="delete" class="Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\DeleteButton"/>
            <button name="back" class="Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\BackButton"/>
        </buttons>
        <namespace>banner_form</namespace>
        <dataScope>data</dataScope>
        <deps>
            <dep>banner_form.banner_form_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>

    <dataSource name="banner_form_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
        </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <submitUrl path="banner/manage/save"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="Aht\BannerSlider\Model\Banner\DataProvider" name="banner_form_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>

    <fieldset name="general">
        <settings>
            <label/>
        </settings>
        <field name="id" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">banner</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <visible>false</visible>
                <dataScope>id</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="name" sortOrder="20" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">banner</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Banner Name</label>
                <dataScope>name</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**EDIT 2:**

I've followed @Rutvee Sojitra solution and get this result.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Add this code on your form code where you want to add innerlisting

```
<insertListing>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="autoRender" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">Name_of_listing_file</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </insertListing>

Make your banner_form.xml file like below:
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">banner_form.banner_form_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General Information</item>
    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
</argument>

<settings>
    <buttons>
        <button name="save_and_continue" class="Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton"/>
        <button name="save" class="Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\SaveButton"/>
        <button name="reset" class="Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\ResetButton"/>
        <button name="delete" class="Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\DeleteButton"/>
        <button name="back" class="Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\BackButton"/>
    </buttons>
    <namespace>banner_form</namespace>
    <dataScope>data</dataScope>
    <deps>
        <dep>banner_form.banner_form_data_source</dep>
    </deps>
</settings>

<dataSource name="banner_form_data_source">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
    </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <submitUrl path="banner/manage/save"/>
    </settings>
    <dataProvider class="Aht\BannerSlider\Model\Banner\DataProvider" name="banner_form_data_source">
        <settings>
            <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
            <primaryFieldName>id</primaryFieldName>
        </settings>
    </dataProvider>
</dataSource>

<fieldset name="general">
    <settings>
        <label/>
    </settings>
    <field name="id" formElement="input">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">banner</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <visible>false</visible>
            <dataScope>id</dataScope>
        </settings>
    </field>
    <field name="name" sortOrder="20" formElement="input">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">banner</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Banner Name</label>
            <dataScope>name</dataScope>
        </settings>
    </field>
</fieldset>
  <fieldset name="banner_information" sortOrder="10">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Banner Information</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <insertListing>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="autoRender" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">banner_listing</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </insertListing>
</fieldset>
```

> I have added below code:

```
 <fieldset name="banner_information" sortOrder="10">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Banner Information</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <insertListing>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="autoRender" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">banner_listing</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </insertListing>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: What does this code do?
I should put it on the ui-component file?
Which is C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Aht\BannerSlider\view\adminhtml\ui_component\banner_form.xml ?

Comment: Yes right add this code in banner_for.xml 
and if your innerlisting name <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">banner_listing </item> then create banner_listing file

Comment: Ohh... I already have banner_listing.xml file, but i dont want to do "grid in tabs" in there, its perfect now.
What i need is only "grid in tabs" in banner_form.xml.
Hmm .. i'm gonna try it now. Thanks, i will report for you later :)

Comment: You can accept this answer if you get solution, so it will help to other to reach there solution

Comment: I cant put it in my banner_form.xml file, it throw an error : Invalid XML file.
Where should i put it? I've tried every where in banner_form.xml :(

Comment: Can you please your banner_form.xml code in question here
So i can check and help you

Comment: Edited. please check :)

Comment: @fudu what your tabname where you want listing?

Comment: tab name?i'm not sure what is that.

Comment: Please see in screenshot which you have uploaded in question:
THere is the "REWARD POINTS" is tab name
what is tab want you create in your code?

Comment: Oh, so that'll be "Banner Information"

Comment: @fudu i have edited my ans and added code for banner_form.xml
please add that code in your file and check

Comment: i dont get it, what did you change in the code?

Comment: what i have added i wrote in ans please check again @fudu

Comment: it give me this result. I've edited the image. Please check

Comment: edited image not display Can you please recheck @fudu

Comment: I've edited. You are only give the grid to me, but what i really need is "grid in tabs" :)

Comment: Banner_form should have parent listing.
What i have explained is absolutely correct. either you implement wrongly or unserstood wrongly

Comment: what is parent listing? :(
what do i need to do now ?
in layout file i have this : <update handle="editor"/>

Comment: that's it, and anything else i do exactly like what u told me to. @@

Comment: Hmm.. well , I've another work now , i need to do like this "C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\adminhtml\layout\catalog_category_edit.xml".
Even when you didn't solved my problem but thanks for your help btw, +1 vote for you my friend :)
sorry because i cant accept your answers

Comment: @RutveeSojitra Can you please look at this question?  https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/242285/48571

Answer (score 1):

Below an example using you render the product grid into the tab and save the selected product into the database.

**Step - 1
Create The File Vendor\ProductsGrid\Setup\InstallSchema.php**

and write the code based on the below file.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ProductsGrid\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * Installs DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

        if (!$installer->tableExists('vendor_faq')) {
            $table = $installer->getConnection()
                ->newTable($installer->getTable('vendor_faq'))
                ->addColumn(
                    'faq_id',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    10,
                    ['identity' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true, 'unsigned' => true]
                )
                ->addColumn('name', Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, ['nullable' => false])
                ->addColumn('question', Table::TYPE_TEXT, '2M', ['default' => ''], 'File path')
                ->addColumn('answer', Table::TYPE_TEXT, '2M', ['default' => ''], 'File path')
                ->addColumn('creation_time', Table::TYPE_DATETIME, null, ['nullable' => false], 'Creation Time')
                ->addColumn('update_time', Table::TYPE_DATETIME, null, ['nullable' => false], 'Update Time')
                ->setComment('Sample table');

            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }

        if (!$installer->tableExists('vendor_product_attachment_rel')) {
            $table = $installer->getConnection()
                ->newTable($installer->getTable('vendor_product_attachment_rel'))
                ->addColumn('faq_id', Table::TYPE_INTEGER, 10, ['nullable' => false, 'unsigned' => true])
                ->addColumn('product_id', Table::TYPE_INTEGER, 10, ['nullable' => false, 'unsigned' => true], 'Magento Product Id')
                ->addForeignKey(
                    $installer->getFkName(
                        'vendor_faq',
                        'faq_id',
                        'vendor_product_attachment_rel',
                        'faq_id'
                    ),
                    'faq_id',
                    $installer->getTable('vendor_faq'),
                    'faq_id',
                    Table::ACTION_CASCADE
                )
                ->addForeignKey(
                    $installer->getFkName(
                        'vendor_product_attachment_rel',
                        'faq_id',
                        'catalog_product_entity',
                        'entity_id'
                    ),
                    'product_id',
                    $installer->getTable('catalog_product_entity'),
                    'entity_id',
                    Table::ACTION_CASCADE
                )
                ->setComment('Faq Product Attachment relation table');

            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**2. Step - 2
Now Create the helper Vendor\ProductsGrid\Helper\Data.php**

(get products tab Url in admin)

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ProductsGrid\Helper;
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $_backendUrl;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    protected $storeManager;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context   $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $backendUrl
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $backendUrl,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_backendUrl = $backendUrl;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
    /**
     * get products tab Url in admin
     * @return string
     */
    public function getProductsGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->_backendUrl->getUrl('productsgrid/faq/products', ['_current' => true]);
    }
}
```

**3. Step - 3
Vendor\ProductsGrid\view\adminhtml\layout\productsgrid_faq_edit.xml**

Now add the tab product grid into the edit layout as well as below

```
<action method="addTab">
    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">attachment_products</argument>
    <argument name="block" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Select Products</item>
        <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Select Products</item>
        <item name="url" xsi:type="helper" helper="Vendor\ProductsGrid\Helper\Data::getProductsGridUrl"></item>
        <item name="class" xsi:type="string">ajax</item>
    </argument>
</action>
```

**4. Step - 4
Create Controller
Vendor\ProductsGrid\Controller\Adminhtml\Faq\Products.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ProductsGrid\Controller\Adminhtml\Faq;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\TestFramework\ErrorLog\Logger;

class Products extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory
     */
    protected $_resultLayoutFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
     * @param Action\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_resultLayoutFactory = $resultLayoutFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultLayout = $this->_resultLayoutFactory->create();
        $resultLayout->getLayout()->getBlock('productsgrid.edit.tab.products')
                     ->setInProducts($this->getRequest()->getPost('faq_products', null));

        return $resultLayout;
    }
}
```

**5. Step - 5
Create Controller
Vendor\ProductsGrid\Controller\Adminhtml\Faq\ProductsGrid.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ProductsGrid\Controller\Adminhtml\Faq;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\TestFramework\ErrorLog\Logger;

class ProductsGrid extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory
     */
    protected $_resultLayoutFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
     * @param Action\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_resultLayoutFactory = $resultLayoutFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultLayout = $this->_resultLayoutFactory->create();
        $resultLayout->getLayout()->getBlock('productsgrid.edit.tab.products')
                     ->setInBanner($this->getRequest()->getPost('faq_products', null));

        return $resultLayout;
    }

}
```

**6. Step - 6
Create Block
Vendor\ProductsGrid\Block\Adminhtml\Faq\Edit\Tab\Products.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ProductsGrid\Block\Adminhtml\Contact\Edit\Tab;

use Vendor\ProductsGrid\Model\FaqFactory;

class Products extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * 
     *
     * @var faqFactory
     */
    protected $faqFactory;

    /**
     * @var  \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    protected $_objectManager = null;

 
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        FaqFactory $faqFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->faqFactory = $faqFactory;
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * _construct
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('productsGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('faq_id')) {
            $this->setDefaultFilter(array('in_product' => 1));
        }
    }

    /**
     * add Column Filter To Collection
     */
    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        if ($column->getId() == 'in_product') {
            $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();

            if (empty($productIds)) {
                $productIds = 0;
            }
            if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));
            } else {
                if ($productIds) {
                    $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => $productIds));
                }
            }
        } else {
            parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * prepare collection
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('sku');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        /* @var $model \Vendor\ProductsGrid\Model\Slide */
        $model = $this->_objectManager->get('\Vendor\ProductsGrid\Model\Faq');

        $this->addColumn(
            'in_product',
            [
                'header_css_class' => 'a-center',
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => 'in_product',
                'align' => 'center',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'values' => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('Product ID'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'name',
            [
                'header' => __('Name'),
                'index' => 'name',
                'class' => 'xxx',
                'width' => '50px',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'sku',
            [
                'header' => __('Sku'),
                'index' => 'sku',
                'class' => 'xxx',
                'width' => '50px',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'price',
            [
                'header' => __('Price'),
                'type' => 'currency',
                'index' => 'price',
                'width' => '50px',
            ]
        );

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/productsgrid', ['_current' => true]);
    }

    /**
     * @param  object $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return '';
    }

    protected function _getSelectedProducts()
    {
        $contact = $this->getContact();
        return $contact->getProducts($contact);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve selected products
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSelectedProducts()
    {
        $faq = $this->getFaq();
        $selected = $faq->getProducts($faq);

        if (!is_array($selected)) {
            $selected = [];
        }
        return $selected;
    }

    protected function getFaq()
    {
        $contactId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('faq_id');
        $faq   = $this->faqFactory->create();
        if ($faqId) {
            $faq->load($faqId);
        }
        return $faq;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**7. Step - 7
Create layout
Vendor\ProductsGrid\view\adminhtml\layout\productsgrid_faq_products.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <container name="root" label="Root">
        <block class="Vendor\ProductsGrid\Block\Adminhtml\Faq\Edit\Tab\Products" name="productsgrid.edit.tab.products"/>
        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Serializer" name="products_grid_serializer">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="grid_block" xsi:type="string">productsgrid.edit.tab.products</argument>
                <argument name="callback" xsi:type="string">getSelectedProducts</argument>
                <argument name="input_element_name" xsi:type="string">products</argument>
                <argument name="reload_param_name" xsi:type="string">faq_products</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </container>
</layout>
```

**8. Step - 8
Create layout
Vendor\ProductsGrid\view\adminhtml\layout\productsgrid_faq_productsgrid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <container name="root" label="Root">
        <block class="Vendor\ProductsGrid\Block\Adminhtml\Faq\Edit\Tab\Products" name="productsgrid.edit.tab.products"/>
    </container>
</layout>
```

**9. Step - 9
Create Save Controller
Vendor\ProductsGrid\Controller\Adminhtml\Faq\save.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ProductsGrid\Controller\Adminhtml\Faq;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\TestFramework\ErrorLog\Logger;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Helper\Js
     */
    protected $_jsHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Vendor\ProductsGrid\Model\ResourceModel\Faq\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_faqCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * \Magento\Backend\Helper\Js $jsHelper
     * @param Action\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Js $jsHelper,
        \Vendor\ProductsGrid\Model\ResourceModel\Faq\CollectionFactory $faqCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_jsHelper = $jsHelper;
        $this->_faqCollectionFactory = $faqCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        if ($data) {

            /** @var \Vendor\ProductsGrid\Model\Faq $model */
            $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Vendor\ProductsGrid\Model\Faq');

            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('faq_id');
            if ($id) {
                $model->load($id);
            }

            $model->setData($data);

            try {
                $model->save();
                $this->saveProducts($model, $data);

                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You saved this Faq.'));
                $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData(false);
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['faq_id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true]);
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the Faq.'));
            }

            $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['faq_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('faq_id')]);
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }

    public function saveProducts($model, $post)
    {
        
        if (isset($post['products'])) {
            $productIds = $this->_jsHelper->decodeGridSerializedInput($post['products']);
            try {
                $oldProducts = (array) $model->getProducts($model);
                $newProducts = (array) $productIds;

                $this->_resources = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
                $connection = $this->_resources->getConnection();

                $table = $this->_resources->getTableName(\Vendor\ProductsGrid\Model\ResourceModel\Faq::TBL_ATT_PRODUCT);
                $insert = array_diff($newProducts, $oldProducts);
                $delete = array_diff($oldProducts, $newProducts);

                if ($delete) {
                    $where = ['faq_id = ?' => (int)$model->getId(), 'product_id IN (?)' => $delete];
                    $connection->delete($table, $where);
                }

                if ($insert) {
                    $data = [];
                    foreach ($insert as $product_id) {
                        $data[] = ['faq_id' => (int)$model->getId(), 'product_id' => (int)$product_id];
                    }
                    $connection->insertMultiple($table, $data);
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the Faq.'));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**I hope this is helpful to you!!**