# Magento 2 save grid data from admin form

Tags: magento2, admin, uicomponent, product-grid

I added a grid in admin form using UI Component by following the answer given here [How to create Grid in Tabs?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/236855/48571)

[image]

Now when I save the data, I don't get the values of selected items in save controller.

Can someone tell me how to save this grid data?

Please see my code.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/vendor_module_blog_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_blog_form.blog_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_blog_form.blog_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">General Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_blog_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Blog\Edit\BackButton</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Blog\Edit\DeleteButton</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Blog\Edit\SaveButton</item>
            <item name="save_and_continue" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Blog\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="blog_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\Blog\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">blog_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">blog_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">blog_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" path="*/*/save" xsi:type="url"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="General">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="content">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">content</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Blog</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">content</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="title">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">title</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Blog</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">title</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <insertListing>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="autoRender" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_blog_index</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </insertListing>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Blog/Save.php

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Blog;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
    ) {
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);
        die();

        if ($data) {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('blog_id');

            $model = $this->_objectManager->create(\Vendor\Module\Model\Blog::class)->load($id);
            if (!$model->getId() && $id) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('This Blog no longer exists.'));
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            }

            $model->setData($data);

            try {
                $model->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved the Blog.'));
                $this->dataPersistor->clear('vendor_module_blog');

                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['blog_id' => $model->getId()]);
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the Blog.'));
            }

            $this->dataPersistor->set('vendor_module_blog', $data);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['blog_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('blog_id')]);
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your grid code and also save contoller code?

Comment: @RutveeSojitra Please see my updated question.

Comment: Are you getting data in dataProvider?
Vendor\Module\Model\Blog\DataProvider

Comment: Let me check it.

Comment: No I am not getting the data in DataProvider.

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the same issue while I am saving data, selected items not getting in the save controller.

I have used this tutorial @ https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-how-to-add-product-grid-in-ui-form-using-uicomponent/

Solution:

Add UI component form name in "data-form-part" below file

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/products/assign_products.phtml

```
<input type="hidden" name="rh_products" data-form-part="custom_form" id="rh_products" value=""  />

to

<input type="hidden" name="rh_products" data-form-part="ui_component_form_name" id="rh_products" value=""  />
```

may be it will help you for finding solution.

Comment: Thanks for giving the solution It's fine for me!!

Answer (score 0):

```
                 <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

add below line in both filed

```
            <field name="content">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">content</item>
               <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Blog</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">content</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="title">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">title</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Blog</item>
               <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">title</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Comment: after changing code please remove generated folder and clean the cache.

Let me know if it can help you

Comment: I don't think it will work. It is for visibility only. Let me try it.

Comment: No It's not working.

Comment: I think you are not getting my point

Comment: I am able to get the title and content data in save controller. What I am not getting is the selected item of grid.

Comment: When I select the first item from grid which has the **ID** 1, I should get this id in my save controller so I can save it in my table. But I am not getting this id.

Comment: Means do you want innerlisting grid  data on save?

Comment: Yesssss. This is what I want :)

Comment: If there are total 10 Ids in grid but I select only 2 ids, then I should get those 2 ids only in my save controller.

Comment: I don't think so it's possible by innerlisting  because for the post data it must be form element.
I haven't tried this one
Thanks for giving something new and interesting question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83161/discussion-between-dinesh-yadav-and-rutvee-sojitra).

Comment: @DineshYadav  Have you found the solution?

Comment: No I have not found the solution. I stopped working on this functionality and then never tried.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most elegant solution, but it works. You can collect the selections using the uiRegistry component.

Assuming that your selections column in the listing component is defined like this:

```
        <selectionsColumn name="ids" component="Vendor_Module/js/grid/columns/onoff" sortOrder="10">
            <settings>
                <controlVisibility>false</controlVisibility>
                <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </selectionsColumn>
```

You can create a custom form provider JS component like this:

```
define(['Magento_Ui/js/form/provider', 'uiRegistry'], function (Provider, registry) {
    'use_strict';

    return Provider.extend({
        save: function (options) {
            var data = this.get('data');
            data.selections = registry.get('aw_raf_product_listing.aw_raf_product_listing.discount_group_product_columns.ids').selected();
            this.set('data', data);
            return this._super(options);
        }
    });
});
```

You then set the form's data source to use this provider like this:

```
    <dataSource name="aw_raf_discount_group_form_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/form/discount-group-form-provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
...
    </dataSource>
```