# Magento 2 Not getting data in Save controller when using Product Grid in UI Component Form in custom module

Tags: uicomponent, adminform, product-grid, magento2.4.5

I have taken reference from below links:

https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-how-to-add-product-grid-in-ui-form-using-uicomponent/

[Magento 2 : How to add a product grid in custom module using ui component?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149833/magento-2-how-to-add-a-product-grid-in-custom-module-using-ui-component)

But still not getting data when form is submitted.
Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Hello @suyati, is there any error appearing?

Comment: No error, product grid is displaying but when i select products and save form, cannot get any data regarding products, just other fields data is fetched.

Comment: Have you tried this solution - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242285/magento-2-save-grid-data-from-admin-form ?

Comment: Yes, already tried it, after adding component form name to 
<input type="hidden" name="rh_products" data-form-part="ui_component_form_name" id="rh_products" value=""  /> it gives blank post parameter like {}