# How to save/load/retain admin Insertlisting component row selections

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

[image]

I'm trying to create an admin form tab like in the picture below, where the following occur:

- On page load, existing selections are already checked in the grid
- On save, new/existing selections in the grid get sent in post request for saving
- On search/filtering, new/existing selections in the grid are retained for eventual saving

Due to the requirements above, I have used the InsertListing ui component:

[DevDocs - InsertListing Component](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-insertlisting.html)

I am not sure how to get the selections to work the way I described above.

Comment: are you able to solve the problem?

Comment: @SagarParikhSGR Insert listing only for display data not for saving the detail

Comment: Please follow this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/236854/magento-2-2-5-how-to-create-grid-in-tabs/315875#315875